# WPS office won't start

Tags: 16.04, wps-office

I just installed WPS office on ubuntu but now whenever I try to launch any of those WPS office software like WPS Writer or WPS Presentation they won't launch.It won't show any error report either. I downloaded the package from its website and then installed it using gnome. I have to make a project and I'm more used to Microsoft office and WPS office seems to be the closest to it in Ubuntu. Also the  LibreOffice seems to lack many features (like word art, styles etc.).  I'm using the 16.04 version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Who says LibreOffice doesn't have Word Art? Have a look at this reference: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14495/what-is-the-word-art-equivalent-in-libreoffice/ Is your question about WPS or LibreOffice?

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm kinda new at LibreOffice and couldn't find it. And my question is about WPS.

Answer (score 1):

Install WPS directly from the Ubuntu Software Center rather than try downloading the source files elsewhere.

Open the USC and navigate to WPS using the search facility

[image]

Having then made your selection click on Install and let the system do all the work for you.

[image]